# Java Http Error Stream Garble

Tags: java, api, https, httpsurlconnection

I am attempting to work with a restful api in Java and am trying to parse server responses when I get an http error code. (The api returns custom responses in JSON).

When I type in the api url in the browser, intentionally passing bad params to get a 422 response, the api returns json explaining what went wrong.

However, in my java code when I use getErrorStream the response seems to be encrypted or encoded. Not sure which.

Can anyone explain where something may be going wrong?

```
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", proxyHost);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", proxyPort);


    URL workfrontProject = new URL(apiURLwithparams);
    HttpsURLConnection httpConn =(HttpsURLConnection) workfrontProject.openConnection();


    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpConn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    httpConn.setReadTimeout(300000);
    httpConn.connect();
    System.out.println("Connected to: "+httpConn.getURL().toString());

    //returns 422 because I pass bad params intentionally
    // hence error stream should be set

    System.out.println("The Response Code is: "+httpConn.getResponseCode());

    Scanner wfAdminIssues = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getErrorStream()));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while (wfAdminIssues.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(wfAdminIssues.next());
    }

    wfAdminIssues.close();
```

Then the error stream output looks like this (had to use image cause the characters won't even copy over).[image: Bad Text]

In the browser, though I get: {"error":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"does not support field (fakeField)"}}

Comment: Could this be deflated? Can you try with an InflaterInputerStream?

Comment: That was exactly right! The content-encoding header indicated it was gzip when I checked response headers. Thanks much!